# gmail authentication for my php website

Tags: php, authentication, openid, gmail, single-sign-on

lI have a php website, I want to first authenticate users from gmail and then let him use my website stuff (like idea used by http://stackoverflow.com)

Following is simple idea I want to implement

if user type www.example.com and he already login to gmail account then he will be directed to www.example.com/services.php

if user is not login then he to will be directed to gmail login page.

I need a working example, I searched alot using term openid, sso, federated login etc, but I could not find any working example

Answer (score 7):

Everything is explained in the [Federated Login for Google Account Users](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID) article by Google (here's a [general explanation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/)). Unfortunately I don't expect anyone here to write the code from scratch for you.

Comment: yes google account, i want a tutorial that help me, I read all these articals

Comment: But these articles explain everything nicely. [This one](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) even gives you JavaScript snippets, just read and learn, don't copy and paste a solution from a tutorial...

Answer (score 3):

Stackoverflow uses his own extension of [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/).

Someone asked this before: [Login system just like stackoverflow's, written in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937168/login-system-just-like-stackoverflows-written-in-php)

Here is a tutorial: http://remysharp.com/2007/12/21/how-to-integrate-openid-as-your-login-system/

Answer (score 2):

By GMail I assume you mean Google Account?

It's not a quick and simple process, since Google takes privacy very seriously. [But here's a full documentation on how to authenticate with Google.](https://developers.google.com/accounts/)